# calculate $\int_C \frac{z^4+2z}{(z-i)^3}dz$ where $i$ is interior to $C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration

So I need to find

$$\int_C \frac{z^4+2z}{(z-i)^3}dz.$$

Here, $i$ is inside of $C$.

**Attempt:**

By Cauchy's integral formula, we have

\begin{align}
\int_C \frac{z^4+2z}{(z-i)^3}dz&=\frac{2\pi i}{2!}\bigg(f^{''}(z^4+2z) \bigg)\bigg\vert_{z=i}\\
&=\pi i (12z^2)\bigg\vert_{z=i}\\
&=-12\pi i.
\end{align}

Am I correct?

Comment: You can ask these type of question in the main chat, there are always people who help who need clarification.

Comment: Yep, it looks correct. And dude, don't let some downvote ruin your mood. It's Christmas. 

Comment: Yes it is correct but https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info *For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.*

Comment: @Accelerator thx man :-)

Comment: @AnneBauval i didnt doubt any step which is why I am here to be certain I arrived at the correct result.

Comment: @anonymous I understood that, but (as indicated in the previous link and quote) this is not how this site works.

Comment: If I can’t go here to double check my work, where do I go??? @AnneBauval

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But again: this site is not for that.